Finding unique rows and cells in between two dataframes & highlighting the differences even when order is different
Hi all I want to take the row differences between two dataframes,
Lets say Dataframe A has 200 rows & Dataframe B has 180 rows , the difference I expect is 20 rows, Here I shall not take any specific column name into picture, Because I am writing solution to compare n number of tables with this one solution
Below example is only for understanding :
Dataframe A                           Dataframe B 
-------------------- ------          ----------------------------
No|Name| iD| address| mail           No|Name| iD| address | mail \
-------------------- ------          -----------------------------
1 | Raj | 01 | xxxxx                 1 | Buv | 03 | lllll | NULL
2 | Kam | 02 | yyyyy                 2 | Kam | 02 | yyyyy | NULL
3 | Buv | 03 | zzzzz                 3 | Raj | 01 | xxxxx | NULL
4 | Ram | 04 | kkkkk
5 | Buv | 05 | ppppp

here I have two dataframes, Dataframe A has 5 rows, but Dataframe B has 3 rows, I want to get output of different entries in this dataset, for example , 
here expected output is :
3 | Buv | 03 | lllll  --- 3 is icluded because address content is mismatch.\
4 | Ram | 04 | kkkkk \
5 | Buv | 05 | ppppp \

I tried to concat both dataframes and tried to take the result out but I cant able to find the exected result
df_diff = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)

The output I expect is :
3 | Buv | 03 | lllll  --- #3 is icluded bcz address content is mismatch.\
4 | Ram | 04 | kkkkk\
5 | Buv | 05 | ppppp


I wish to create a new dataframe df3 and would like to store the difference data in new dataframe, , Different rows will be there in the new dataframe, And where only cell mismatch on existing rows, I want to highlight that cell with yellow color or any color
Problem faced : indexing in pandas as df will automatically takes it index
Summing both the df and got the result
color difference is secondary but I want to take generic code to take out the differences 
___________________________________________________________________________
Another Example : 
[![here I have 15 rows with detail of football players], Lets consider this is my df1[1]][1]


---------------------------------------------------------------[![Sheet 2 have only 13 rows, 2 rows are missing ,that is : [![\]\[2\]][2]][2]][3]


------------------------------------------------------------------------
**Here I want to print the entire rows which is there in df1 and not in df2. Which means , My output should be**\
[![enter image description here][4]][4]


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/kZlD5M0b.jpg
  [2]: https://i.sstatic.net/5AgUCDHO.png
  [3]: https://i.sstatic.net/GPaAnewQ.jpg
  [4]: https://i.sstatic.net/TM1ORCVJ.png


"Lets say Dataframe A has 200 rows & Dataframe B has 180 rows , the difference I expect is 20 rows". From your example, your left df has 5 rows, your right df has 3 rows, and the suggested output still has three rows. So, how does that work? Please adjust your example using the method suggested in my comment below. Or at any rate, adjust your example to properly reflect the desired output.

Your edit needs improvement. 1) If the first example, your original one to which I just referred above, is wrong then get rid of it. If it is correct, then explain better what the logic is. The "df1 = 200 rows, df2 = 180, I need = 20 rows", as I just explained, does not apply. So, fix that. 2) With your second example: post the data as text, not as images. People are not going to copy all of that manually. Also, it is not minimal. Your first df with the football players has 10 columns and 15 rows. Surely, that can be reduced to say 4 columns and 4 rows, or similar. Etc.

IIUC correctly, you are asking 2 questions:

There are 2 DataFrames (df1 and df2) that share the key ['Name', 'iD']. We need a merged DataFrame (out), that preserved from df1 the entries not found in df2, and from df2 only the entries that contain an update from df1 (in the column 'address').

Next, we want to highlight in out, the value in column 'address' if it concerns an update.


(I'm ignoring the request about np.nan / NULL as irrelevant to the desired output, which doesn't include column 'mail'. Nor should it be included in a merge, since NaNs are not seen as equal.)
Question 2 implies that we need a source flag for each row in out. Using pd.concat in the answer by @mozway, at least in present form, will not provide you one. Let's try with pd.merge:
1. pd.merge with source
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cols = ['Name', 'iD', 'address']

out = (pd.merge(df1[cols], df2[cols], how='outer', indicator='source')
       .query('source != "both"')
       .pipe(lambda x: x[~(x.duplicated(['Name', 'iD'], keep=False) 
                           & x['source'].eq('left_only'))])
       )

Output:
  Name  iD address      source
3  Ram  04   kkkkk   left_only
4  Buv  05   ppppp   left_only
5  Buv  03   lllll  right_only # updated row

Explanation / Intermediates

Select relevant columns (cols) and apply pd.merge with how=outer and indicator='source' to get a FULL OUTER JOIN with a 'source' column added:

pd.merge(df1[cols], df2[cols], how='outer', indicator='source')

  Name  iD address      source
0  Raj  01   xxxxx        both # will be deleted with `query`
1  Kam  02   yyyyy        both # will be deleted with `query`
2  Buv  03   zzzzz   left_only # will be deleted with boolean indexing
3  Ram  04   kkkkk   left_only
4  Buv  05   ppppp   left_only
5  Buv  03   lllll  right_only # updated row


Use df.query to filter out both, which we won't need either way.

In the remaining DataFrame, we will have some duplicates: both left_only and right_only for the same key. For these, we want to filter out left_only rows. Use boolean indexing with two conditions:

Get a Series with True for all duplicates on the keys with df.duplicated with keep=False.
Get a Series with True for each row with 'left_only' with Series.eq

Where both conditions are True (use &) a row is a duplicate and 'left_only'. We need to keep all rows except such rows. Hence we need the inverse: ~(cond1 & cond2).

Use df.pipe to perform this filter on our merged result immediately after the query.



2. highlight updated 'address' values
Assuming the use of Jupyter Notebook, you can use the Styler class for this. E.g.:
def highlight_changed(subset, data):
    return np.where(data == 'right_only', 'background: yellow', '')

out.style.hide('source', axis=1).apply(highlight_changed, 
                                       subset='address', 
                                       data=out['source'])

Output:

Explanation

First, use df.style.hide to hide the 'source' column from the final result.
Next, chain df.style.apply, passing a function (highlight_changed), the label for the column on which we apply the function (subset='address'), and **kwargs for the function (here: data=df['source']).
The function itself simply checks np.where, changing the background to 'yellow' for each row that contains 'right_only'.


Data used
data1 = {'No': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5}, 
         'Name': {0: 'Raj', 1: 'Kam', 2: 'Buv', 3: 'Ram', 4: 'Buv'}, 
         'iD': {0: '01', 1: '02', 2: '03', 3: '04', 4: '05'}, 
         'address': {0: 'xxxxx', 1: 'yyyyy', 2: 'zzzzz', 3: 'kkkkk', 4: 'ppppp'}, 
         'mail': {0: np.nan, 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: np.nan, 4: np.nan}}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'No': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}, 
         'Name': {0: 'Buv', 1: 'Kam', 2: 'Raj'}, 
         'iD': {0: '03', 1: '02', 2: '01'}, 
         'address': {0: 'lllll', 1: 'yyyyy', 2: 'xxxxx'}, 
         'mail': {0: 'NULL', 1: 'NULL', 2: 'NULL'}}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)


If you want a flag with concat you just need to add keys ;) Regarding the second part, be careful this won't work if you have more than just "address" as extra columns. But I guess OP should be clear about that (and this should be a separate question)

@mozway. Sure. I'm just trying to show how this works (on this particular set) with the method that was yesterday suggested as a duplicate on the very same question (which OP should at the very least now delete). Incidentally, occurs to me that this particular variant of concat / merge is not really properly covered in any of the 'canonical' posts. Or is it?

Hi I am looking for the generic solution, Here you have filtered with Column names, My solution is like should work for any dataframes, without filter by coloumn names, I have tried few different ways but nothing helps,. Lets say, I have 200 rows in df1 and 180 rowa in df2, only that 20 rows are my output ,. And main thing is df1's row1 is done need to be df2s row1.. it can be row 60 also

Please update your question with a minimal example that fully reflects the result you are looking for. Add the sample as a pd.DataFrame constructor. E.g., use df.to_dict()) and pass the reduced result (data) to input = pd.DataFrame(data), and post that in a code block, between triple back ticks (```). Next, also add the adjusted, desired output, based on that very example.

I am making detailed and real example , will be upload it shortly

Yes, That question is SOF marked as duplicate and the root question they refer is anti-merge, it is totally irrelevant to my question, I am struggling to solve this for past 2 weeks :(

IIUC, you can use concat and two rounds of drop_duplicates:
cols = ['Name', 'iD']

out = (pd.concat([dfA, dfB])
         .drop_duplicates(subset=dfA.columns.difference(['No']+cols),
                          keep=False)
         .drop_duplicates(subset=cols, keep='last')
         # optional: to keep original column and No order
         [dfA.columns].sort_values(by='No', ignore_index=True)
      )

Output:
   No Name  iD address  mail
0   1  Buv   3   lllll   NaN
1   4  Ram   4   kkkkk   NaN
2   5  Buv   5   ppppp   NaN


As I mentioned previous command I am looking for generic solution. Hi I am looking for the generic solution, Here you have filtered with Column names, My solution is like should work for any dataframes, without filter by coloumn names, I have tried few different ways but nothing helps,. Lets say, I have 200 rows in df1 and 180 rowa in df2, only that 20 rows are my output ,. And main thing is df1's row1 is done need to be df2s row1.. it can be row 60 also

I made some changes in your code and executed but there is a problem in filteration, The differences rows are there in df2 as well

@Arockia can you update your question with a counter-example?

I have drafted the question for better understanding.. For further more explanation, happy to show you the problem, Maybe if you need I can prepare some sample excel sheets and can share
